# Setting Model in AngularJS Control Not Updating View (something...)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-controller

I am experiencing issues with updating values in my AngularJS controller and having them properly reflecting in my model.

I have the following `form` in my view:

```
<form name="formSignIn" id="formSignIn" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="guestName">Name or Employee ID</label>
    <div class="input-group merged">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestName" ng-model="name" typeahead="person.name as person.displayName for person in getTypeaheadValues($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="onTypeaheadSelect($item, $model, $label)" placeholder="Enter Name or Employee ID">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="guestOrg">Organization</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestOrg" ng-model="organization" placeholder="Organization">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="guestPurpose">Purpose</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestPurpose" ng-model="purpose" placeholder="Why are you visiting today?">
  </div>
</form>
```

I initialize my `ng-model` values at the top of my controller:

```
$scope.name = "";
$scope.organization = "";
$scope.purpose = "";
```

I then have two functions that clear out the values, based on the visitor hitting the "Clear" or "Sign In" button:

```
$scope.onSignInClick = function()
{
    // show confirmation
    $scope.leftContent = "confirm";

    // clear the form
    $scope.name = null;
    $scope.organization = null;
    $scope.purpose = null;

    // display the form again after a short pause
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.leftContent = "splash";
    }, 3000);
}

$scope.onClearClick = function()
{
    // confirm function is being called
    console.log("clear");

    // clear the form (trying multiple ways)
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.organization = null;
    $scope.purpose = "abc123";
}
```

My `onSignInClick` function... works without fail.  No troubles.

My `onClearClick` function... never works in a consistent way.  Sometimes `organization` is cleared, sometimes `purpose` is populated (I am updating the value in the code above to show that just "clearing" the value is not the problem).  Depending on what fields I type in, or auto-populate via typeahead, the results of `onClearClick` differ.

I have tried removing the typeahead (AngularUI-Bootstrap Typeahead directive) but that did not solve the problem.

Why are my values sometimes being updated in the view, and sometimes not?

Comment: always best to use object for models...instead of primitives due to scope inheritance

Comment: @charlietfl, good to know - thank you!  I updated my primitives to an object and things are clearing as planned.  Answer form would be appreciated so I may continue to extol!